# Bundle Item won't list Downloadable items

Tags: downloadable, bundle, virtual

For Magento 1.7.0.2

My new bundle item, when I search items to add to the bundle, it only lists virtual and simple. I need downloadable. How do I get this?

Other information:
1. I'm switching to another platform in two months, so I'm not interested in upgrading to 1.9
2. I use jfusion with my Joomla sites, so upgrading would cause a ton of headaches there. So again - I'm not doing it.
3. I cached and re-indexed
4. I create this bundle every year. Last year's 2014 bundle I duplicated and removed the bundle items that were in there and went to add the new ones - and none of the downloadable items appear. Never ran into this issue before.

Answer (score 1):

My fix - in the config.xml file I changed:
< !---< bundle>--->
< !---< allowed_selection_types>--->
< !---< downloadable/>--->
< !---< /allowed_selection_types>--->
< !---< /bundle>--->'

to:
< bundle>
< allowed_selection_types>
< downloadable/>
< /allowed_selection_types>
< /bundle>

No idea why < !--- was in there. Perhaps a freelance programmer from the past was trying to get future business